# VSCode: Open file from file explorer with Enter key on Mac OSX

Tags: visual-studio-code

When using VSCode on Windows, I can navigate the file explorer and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the focused file and the file will open in the editor. On my Mac, however, when I do this, VSCode will open the rename input as follows:

[image]

I'm not sure why it does this.  Even in other text editors (e.g. Atom), the default behavior is to open the file on <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Is there any way to change this behavior so that the file opens on <kbd>Enter</kbd>? The only workaround I've found so far is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, which opens the file in a new pane, but with a 3 pane limit in VSCode, this is quite limiting.

Comment: By their documentation, I think that the only way is to right click and select Reveal in Finder (ou can also navigate to the location of a file or folder in the native Explorer by right-clicking on a file or folder and selecting Reveal in Explorer (or Reveal in Finder on the Mac).) [The Basics](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/codebasics) and [Key Bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings)

Comment: @rmjoia Sorry I wasn't clear.  I'm not trying to reveal a file in Explorer or Finder.  I just want to open the file.  When I click Enter, VSCode wants me to rename the file on Mac.  I don't want to rename the file, I just want to open it.  It works as expected in Windows but not Mac.

Comment: Open in vs code? Like for editing? Open how?

Comment: Yes, I just want to open the file in VSCode for editing without taking my fingers off the keyboard.  I do it all of the time in Atom, Visual Studio, and even VSCode for Windows, but I can't seem to do it in VSCode for Mac.  It keeps trying to rename the file when I hit enter (per my screenshot above).

Comment: Ok, I'm removing my answer then, since it doesn't add anything to the question. I would recommend to use the VSCode forum to request as a feature or maybe get a hint from the community.

Comment: An explanation for this behaviour is that 'Enter' is the shortcut in OS X to rename a file - try it in Finder :)

Comment: To focus sidebar we can use cmd+0 by default :)

Answer (score 256, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this problem, the keyboard shortcut to open a file from the file explorer in VSCode on a Mac is:

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

This also works in Finder.

Comment: +1 But this replaces the existing opened file-tab. Any idea how to open in a new tab, but in the same panel?

Comment: @johnny-oshika You can disable preview behavior in your settings by adding ```"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false``` and ```"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": false```

Comment: @DimaKuzmich that worked great! Setting just the first one, `"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false`, was enough to make it open each file in its own tab

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why they made this so hard to figure out. I can't even find a command for Cmd + Down in the command list.

Comment: They [appear to be working on a fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43676#issuecomment-365867439) which should be out with the next insiders' release.

Comment: @pavsaund Ctrl+Enter on mac appears to open it in a new tab

Comment: does anyone know the equivalent shortcut in Linux to this CMD+Down ?

Comment: I guess they wanted to remain consistent with OSX's Finder experience...

Comment: By default it seems that Cmd+down but also `L` are defined as shortcuts. The command is called `list.select` so if you go to the Keyboard Shortcuts in VSCode and search for that command, you'll find the mappings there.

Comment: @AymericBouzyaybbyk yeah, not intuitive for me either, but I'm not a Mac person. Maybe intuitive for those Mac users? The behavior is the same as that of Finder.

Answer (score 46):

I ended up compiling a few solutions here together to get the following `keybinding.json` editions (Open via `Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts > keybindings.json`):

```
  {
    "key": "cmd+enter",
    "command": "renameFile",
    "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "-renameFile",
    "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus"
  },
  {
    "key": "enter",
    "command": "list.select",
    "when": "listFocus && !inputFocus"
  }
```

Comment: This makes the explorer window completely navigable.  Now I don't have to click to navigate the file-tree.  I just CMD-SHIFT-E from the editor to shift focus over to the file explorer, arrow-key over to another file, and press enter to open the file and shift focus back to the editor.  Perfectly intuitive.  Thank you.

Comment: If you are like me you just want to put this in a JSON file.... command + shift + p opens up command palette and search for "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)" and that leads to this file

Comment: Even easier than @iamnotsam ' s answer is to press F1 to open cmd palette in VSCode.

Answer (score 28):

In version 1.19.2, on the mac I was able to go to keyboard shortcuts (menu bar > code > preferences > keyboard shortcuts), search for "rename," and edit "renameFile" ("When" value is "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !inputFocus") changing the shortcut to "cmd+enter."

You can also past the following in your keybindings.json (there's a link to it on the keyboard shortcuts page):

```
{
  "key": "cmd+enter",
  "command": "renameFile",
  "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !inputFocus"
}
```

Enter now opens the highlighted file in the explorer and ctrl+enter puts it in rename/edit mode.

---

–Edit–

After I upgraded to 1.21.0 the enter key started functioning as renameFile again. cmd+enter still functioned as renameFile as well. To fix this either go to menu bar > code > preferences > keyboard shortcuts and right-click the offending entry and remove it or add a hyphen/minus sign to the beginning of the command in keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "enter",
  "command": "-renameFile",
  "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus && !explorerResourceIsRoot && !inputFocus"
}
```

Answer (score 19):

On my Mac, simply hitting the Spacebar opens the file for me.

Comment: Spacebar opens the file but keeps focus on the Explorer. This would be useful for opening a few different files without having to switch back and forth, but it's different from the command that opens the file and focuses on the editor.

Comment: After opening the file, pressing CMD+Shift+E will toggle the focus to your file if you wanted to edit your file

Answer (score 12):

- `SPACE`: open but keep focus on Explorer
  (`filesExplorer.openFilePreserveFocus` command)
- `CMD+Down`: open and
  focus the opened file (`explorer.openAndPassFocus` command)

You can change them in "Code - Preferences - Keyboard Shortcuts":
[image: Keyboard Shortcuts (Code - Preferences - Keyboard Shortcuts)]

Answer (score 11):

So I ran into this as well, but the keyboard shortcuts that I ended using is to map `cmd+enter` to rename and removing the renameFile from `enter`.

```
{
  "key": "cmd+enter",
  "command": "renameFile",
  "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus"
},
{
  "key": "enter",
  "command": "-renameFile",
  "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus"
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The slightly longer negated binding from [bkidd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48387316/2025495) is what was produced in the keybindings.json after choosing "remove" using the GUI-editor. This worked for me in VSCode 1.24.1.

Answer (score 9):

`cmd+down` does NOT work for me using VSCode 1.10.2 on Mac 10.10.5.

However, `cmd+enter` does work for me.

Or if you want to set your own keybinding to open a file from File Explorer, add these lines to your `keybindings.json`:

```
// open file from File Explorer
{ "key": "enter", "command": "list.select",
                     "when": "explorerViewletVisible && filesExplorerFocus" },
```

(Of course, you can change `enter` to any key combination you want).

Answer (score 7):

I tried to remove the shortcut of "Rename", which has the Keybinding of "Enter". Then it opens the file properly when I press "Enter".

Answer (score 2):

For me, I have to do `command` `0` and then do a `command` `down`
This brings me to the explorer and then opens the file I select.
In Atom, I just had to hit `enter` to open the file, I find this to be a strange behavior. `vscode v 1.21.1` on `OSX`

Answer (score 0):

When opening a file from the explorer you may want to consider adding a binding for the `explorer.openAndPassFocus` shortcut, which solves the original poster's issue of opening the file in a new pane.

[vs code shortcut for opening file from explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMj4k.png)

Answer (score 0):

You also can press l key, when jumping by j and k

Comment: Can you elaborate? `j` and `k` don't allow me to navigate up and down the solution explorer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In preferences:

Code -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts

Add this to your keybindings.json

```
{

    "key": "ctrl+n",
    "command": "workbench.action.files.newFile"
}
```

within the array that may or may not contain other keybindings you have set. 
Save keybindings.json

Then when you navigate to a directory in the file explorer, you can create a new file with ctrl+n

Comment: hmmm, could it be that you're answering a different question?  This question is about opening an existing file.

Answer (score -3):

Not sure why the "enter" behavior is different, I am not sure "enter" alone is set in the keybindings on your system or its just defaults to different behaviors based on OS standards...

The good news is, what you are looking for is CTRL+P or CTRL+O

CTRL+P let's you find a file, and CTRL+O should open it  (the exact behavior you'd like)

You may also be able to add "Enter" as a possibility for the "workbench.action.files.openFile" command, but not sure if that will break anything if you do.
 Try it, or just get used to using CTRL+O on both platforms!

More info:

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings

Comment: I use CTRL+P quite extensively, but sometimes I want to navigate the file explorer (CMD+0 or CMD+SHIFT+E) and then open a file, all using the keyboard.  Strangely, this doesn't seem possible on the Mac.

Comment: Me too @JohnnyOshika, I'm a `VIM` user and I'm used to having nerd commenter that displays a sidebar with the file structure like `sublime` or `Atom`. I guess I have to get used to using `vscode`

Comment: I'm in the same boat as @JohnnyOshika - I usually use CTRL+P, but sometimes want to use the explorer view to navigate then open the file