# VSCode - navigate in the file tree with the keyboard

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I love VS Code, but I am really missing one feature from its big brother, Visual Studio.

In Visual Studio, you load the file in the editor when you navigate to it, and if you press enter, you jump into the editor and can start editing the file.

How can I do the same in VS Code?

[VS Code keyboard shortcuts reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-reference)

Comment: I have the same issue and I find the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157786/vscode-open-file-from-file-explorer-with-enter-key-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 50):

To [Show Explorer / Toggle Focus](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_display) press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in Windows/Linux,
in macOS press <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

It will focus on the explorer sidebar, then you can navigate through the file tree with the arrow-keys.

Comment: Thanks I am aware of the shortcut but I want to see the content of a file when I navigate up and down in the tree

Comment: Ohh.. got it. But @MartinAndersen I've tested it here and it seems to work as you want (pressing enter opens the file). I'm using VSCode Version 1.16.0

Comment: Is there any way that we don't need to press `Enter` so that it behaves the same as Windows file Explorer? (you can see the content in the display pane as soon as you select a file)

Comment: Use this in combination with the Vim extension and you can navigate through sidebar with `j` `k` and `l`

Comment: So there's no way to have the files open when the focus moves down? I need to check that an entire folder of images actually has the images in them and not curl errors. Having them load as I navigate with the down-arrow is sort of expected behavior in any editor prior to VSCode. Enter is the shortcut for "rename file".

Comment: I was able to go up and down with the UP/DOWN arrow keys, but would be nicer to type the file_name and it takes me there, instead of going up and down.

Answer (score 28):

On a MacOS, you'd use `CMD`+`SHIFT`+`E` to focus on the sidebar. Then you can use the arrow keys to navigate up and down the tree. To open a file or expand a folder, you can hit the `spacebar` key.

Comment: I'm on Windows so the sidebar open command is different, but the really fantastic discovery was that pressing Enter while focused on a file opens the file and transfers focus to the editor, but pressing Spacebar opens the editor while leaving focus in the sidebar. This lets me jump between sidebar files very quickly using just the arrow keys and spacebar.  Thanks a lot!